# checkbox filtering in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, filter, checkbox

I have such data:

```
const dataList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'obj1',
    published: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'obj2',
    published: true,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'obj3',
    published: false,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'obj4',
    published: true,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'obj5',
    published: false,
  },
];
```

I also have two checkboxes with this structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDKbF.png)

```
filterList = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'published',
      label: 'published',
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'unpublished',
      label: 'unpublished',
      checked: false,
    },
  ],
```

how do I filter this kind of data using these checkboxes? I have implemented switching their state, but I don't understand how to filter the data

I'm trying to implement this in a function

```
const applyFilter = () => {
    let updData = dataList;
    const filterChecked = filterList.filter((item: any) => item.checked);

    if (filterChecked.length) {
      // how to dynamically substitute data from checkboxes?
      updData = updData.filter((item) => item.published === //true//);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt at a minimal example that hopefully gives a clear overview of how it's possible to filter elements. You can use your state to control how the elements are filtered out of the list, and then render those that remain:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [showingBs, setShowingBs] = React.useState(true);

    return (<div>
      <input
        type = "checkbox"
        checked = {showingBs}
        onChange = {
          () => setShowingBs(!showingBs)
        }
      />
        {
          ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b']
            .filter(x => showingBs || x !== 'b')
            .map(x => <p>{x}</p>)
        }
      </div>)
    }

    ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("mount"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="mount"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't understand yet how to apply this to filtering my data. I get from checkboxes:
: 
{id: 1, title: 'published', label: 'published', checked: true}
1
: 
{id: 2, title: 'unpublished', label: 'unpublished', checked: false}

Comment: Sure - so from that state you know which ones are selected. You can use the title. If the box with title publish is not checked, then filter out those that are published etc etc